# Stay on a current tab after after submitting a form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to stay on a specif tab ( in this case tab2 ) but after clicking the submit button the tab reverts to tab 1 which has the default class of active. I have hit a brick wall with this one.

Here is my example **[[jsfiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/cwHQA/1/)**:

HTML:

```
<ul class='tabs'>
            <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
<div id='tab1'>
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consssectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis placerat dolor id aliquet. Sed a orci in justo blandit commodo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.</p>
                <form id="form1" action="" method="post">            
      <input id="button-1" name="" type="submit" />
</form>
        </div>
<div id='tab2'>
<a name="tab2"></a>
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <p>Aenean et est tortor. In pharetra pretium convallis. Mauris sollicitudin ligula non mi hendrerit varius. Fusce convallis hendrerit mauris, eu accumsan nisl aliquam eu.</p>

    <form id="form2" action="" method="post">            
      <input id="button-2" name="" type="submit" />
</form>
        </div>
<div>
  <h2>RESULTS </h2>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
        $active = $links.first().addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));
        $links.not(':first').each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

​
CSS:

```
*         {padding:0; margin:0;}
html      {padding:15px 15px 0;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
p, h3     {margin-bottom:15px;}
div       {padding:10px;width:600px;background:#fff;}
ul.tabs   {margin-left:2px;}
#tab1, #tab2 {border-top: solid 1px #ccc;margin-top: -1px; }
#tab2      {display:none;}a
ul.tabs li  {list-style:none;display:inline;}
ul.tabs li a   {padding:5px 10px;display:inline-block;background:#666;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;}
ul.tabs li a.active {background:#fff;color:#000;border: solid 1px #ccc; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;}
```

​

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In future please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Comment: Sorry I'm still getting used to using this site but yes I agree I'll do that now

Comment: `@`NickP: Not a problem; just a friendly hint :). You'll see I've done it for you on this occasion... but just a thing to note for the future :).

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidAccordionIndex" runat="server" Value="0" />
```

Put this in your coding and change the script as follows

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
header: "h3",
autoHeight: false,
event: "mousedown",
active: activeIndex,
ui: "PageName.aspx",
change: function (event, ui) {
var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
$('#<% =hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val(index);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="tab">
<ul>
            <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<form id="form1" action="?tab=tab1" method="post"> 

The jQuery function:
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tab").tabs();
        var param = $(document).getUrlParam('tab');
        if (param !=null)
            $("#tab").tabs('select',param);
        else 
            $("#tab").tabs();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify tab in URL. 
A tab is an anchor in a URL like: yourURL/#tab

```
<form id="form2" action="#tab2" method="post">            

</form>
```

Comment: This makes it simple. Thanks for this comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy.
after submit your form you have to click on tab you want automatically.
first put Id in your tabs like this

`<a href='#tab1' id=idtab1 >
<a href='#tab2' id=idtab2 >`

and after that just use the Javascript before body close

`<script>
document.getElementById('idtab2').click();
 </script>`

Comment: Thanks Mohsen, this is an old question but I ended up using a cookie based/stored on the active tab. Interesting how many views this question has generated - Agreed! it was easy in the end

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in your Submit button's `onclick()` event to post-back values asynchronously. That way, there won't be a window reload, as the postback will occur in the background.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form2">            
      <input id="button-2" type="button" onclick="submit();" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
​function submit(){
   $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "submit.php",
  data: { param1: "param1", param2: "param2" }
  }).done(function() {
      alert( "Submitted" );
  });
  }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Add e.preventDefault(); to the submit button.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Widmore/cwHQA/2/

Comment: I commented that out - form won't submit otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the "id" of the selected tab inside a variable when the user clicks the send button and restore it after the form is posted to the server.
Take a look at the Form events for more information

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery Form Plugin to submit the form via ajax instead of a full page refresh: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: devlife - Unfortunately I'm using an enterprise search engine so I'm a little restricted but I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

This what HTML for tab looks like -

```
<div class="tab">
   <input type="button"  class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'NewSummaries')" value="New Summaries" id="NewSummariesTab">
   <input type="button"  class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'EditedSummaries')" value="Edited Summaries" id="EditedSummariesTab">
</div>
```

You can save the ID of previously clicked tab in a session variable using Javascript.
Something like -

```
function openTab(evt, categoryName) {
  
  {....Your onclick functionality....}

  localStorage.setItem('CurTab',categoryName)
  var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('CurTab');
  console.log(activeTab);
}
```

So, the session variable 'curTab' will have your last clicked tab id.
And then you can add the below script at very start of your  tag. This will by default click the last active tab-

```
<script>
document.getElementById(localStorage.getItem('CurTab')).click();
</script>
```