# Stay on a <li> tab after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I stay on the current tab after submitting form or refresh the page. The tabs are made with `li`, not with `div`.
These are the tabs:

```
<ul class="tabs">
 <li><a href="#profile" class="active"> Profile </a></li>
 <li><a href="#favourites"> Favourites </a></li>
 <li><a href="#settings"> Settings </a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="tabs-content">
 <li id="profile">TEXT</li>
 <li id="favourites">TEXT</li>
 <li id="settings">submit form...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560613/stay-on-a-current-tab-after-after-submitting-a-form-using-jquery Maybe this link can help

Comment: If you could help me with the code.. I am not very familiar with javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this, using [CSS `:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

```css
.tabs-content li {
  display: none;
}

#profile:target,
#favourites:target,
#settings:target {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>
    <a href="#profile" class="active"> Profile </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#favourites"> Favourites </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#settings"> Settings </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li id="profile">profile</li>
  <li id="favourites">favourites</li>
  <li id="settings">settings</li>
</ul>
```

And if you submit a form i.e. in settings, make sure the form action have the hash too.

```
<form action="save_settings.aspx#settings">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try capturing current `li` element when form is submitted. Also, add `id` to each element.

```
// assuming class for `submit` button is `submit`
    $('.submit').on('click', function(){
      var linkId = $('.active').atr('id');
    });
```

And after page refresh or submitting the form call:

```
$('#'+ linkId).click();
```

**Note**: Assuming that you are submitting form through Ajax, if not then you need to pass stored `var` value to backend and pass it back with response to view and maybe click on it then by following the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the current active tab's index i.e., `li` index to localstorage/cookies and on page load retrieve the value and make that `li` as active tab.

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // 1 should be replaced with the active li's index
    localStorage.setItem("currentActiveTab", "1");
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

On document ready, do some thing like

```
if (localStorage.currentActiveTab) {
    $('li').eq(localStorage.currentActiveTab).click();
}
```

Comment: might want to delete this object as well when page is changed otherwise it will waste some space in local storage.